# Class not found when calling another class name in namespace

Tags: php

When I create a class object dynamically I don't understand why it **throws class not found**. However, if I will remove **namespace  App\Controls** and **use App\Controls\one**, it worked perfectly example code:

```
namespace App\Controls;

use App\Controls\one;
    
class one {
    public static function test_one($className, $object) {
        return $object((new $className));
    }
}

class two {
    public function language($lang) {
        echo 'I love '.$lang;
    }
}


one::test_one('two', function($table) {
    $table->language('PHP');
});
```

from this structure I want to call class two depends on the value I input. I also include **use App\Controls\two** but still not working, but that's not the case because supposedly I will not add another **use App\Controls\className** just to call create another class object and it's not possible from PHP.

Comment: For starters, don't post your title in all Caps; it sounds like you're yelling, and no one wants to help people that yell at them...

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, [namespaces](https://www.php.net/namespaces) are resolved when the code is *compiled*, not when it is *run*.

So, when you write this:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
use MyOthernamespace\SomeClass;

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new SomeClass;
```

The compiler looks at the current namespace, and the class names you've "imported", and compiles the code as though you'd written this:

```
$foo = new MyNamespace\Foo;
$bar = new MyOthernamespace\SomeClass;
```

(Note that you don't need to `use` anything in the *current* namespace; that's assumed as the default prefix for everything.)

In your code, the compiler doesn't know that the `'two'` is going to be used as a class name, so it doesn't change it; so when the dynamic code runs, it comes out literally as:

```
return $object((new two));
```

Which won't work - there isn't a class called `two`, only one called `App\Controls\two`.

The solution to this is the magic `::class` syntax, which tells the compiler to expand something like it would for a class name, and then turn it into a string. It's important to know that despite the name, *it doesn't actually care if the thing it's expanding is a class, or exists at all*, it just expands it and assumes you know what you're doing with it.

So if you write this:

```
namespace App\Controls;

one::test_one(two::class, function($table) {
    $table->language('PHP');
});
```

It will be expanded *by the compiler* to this:

```
App\Controls\one::test_one('App\Controls\two', function($table) {
    $table->language('PHP');
});
```

Then when it gets into the dynamic code, it will be referencing the right class name, and run the code as though it was this:

```
return $object((new App\Controls\two));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I looking for.